# Plotly angle is wrong

Tags: charts, plotly

I'm using plotly to create pie/donut charts. I figured out how to get the data to sort and "start" at degree 0. However, this latter feature really doesn't work. With sorting:true and rotation:0 this is what you get:
[image]

So while it DOES sort counterclockwide, the '0" rotation is misleading. It starts at the END of the first slice and puts *that* at degree 0. Every time this chart refreshes with different data, that first slice is different so I can't easily just change the rotation to something like "-101" because it will be different every time.

Is there a plotly setting that tells the chart to start the rotation at the BEGINNING of the first slice?